# how to change the src of the frame dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frames

I am having a "cars.html" HTML file having three frames within a frameset

```
<frameset id="help" rows="10%,5%,90%">

<frame id="pageTitle" frameborder=0 scrolling=no src="cars_pageTitle.html">
<frame id="pageMenu" frameborder=0 marginheight="0" src="cars_pageMenu.html">
<frame id="pageContent" frameborder=0 marginheight="0" src="#">

 </frameset>
```

"cars_pageMenu.html" has the menu bar
I assign this to the src of the second frame

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function carRequestMenu()
{
     alert(document.getElementById("pageContent"));
document.getElementById("pageContent").src='cars_requestMenuContent.html';
}
</script>

<BODY>
 <div id="pageToolbar" style="width=100%;height:10px;background-color:FF3333">
      <menu type="toolbar" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px">
       <button type="button" onclick="carRequestMenu()">Request a Car</button>
       </menu>
 </div>
</BODY>
```

when i click the button "Request a Car" the carRequestMenu() function is called
the alert shows null value.I am not able to change the src dynamically.
thanks

Comment: `NULL` means it is not getting any thing. Check the console what error you are having

Comment: The console also says it is null

Answer (score 1):

You can use window.open and specify the target name:

```
    <frameset id="help" rows="10%,5%,90%">

<frame id="pageTitle" frameborder=0 scrolling=no src="cars_pageTitle.html">
<frame id="pageMenu" frameborder=0 marginheight="0" src="cars_pageMenu.html">
<frame id="pageContent" name="pageContent" frameborder=0 marginheight="0" src="#">

 </frameset>


<script type="text/javascript">
function carRequestMenu()
{
     window.open('cars_requestMenuContent.html','pageContent');
}
</script>

<BODY>
 <div id="pageToolbar" style="width=100%;height:10px;background-color:FF3333">
      <menu type="toolbar" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px">
       <button type="button" onclick="carRequestMenu()">Request a Car</button>
       </menu>
 </div>
</BODY>
```

Comment: Hi Alex Wang, it is opening a new window . But i want the change to happen in the same page

Comment: I got the problem solved , instead of id i used name and followed the comment of alex